# Pycharm **kwargs auto-complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Hi I'm trying to make pycharm's auto-complete works with **kwargs. To do this I'm wrote a doc string using epytext syntax which has a way to declare keyword arguments with `@keyword p:` but it doesn't works.

[image: Example]

Do someone know the way to fix it?

P.S. I have changed a docstring format in PyCharm setting.

Comment: you have no body inside the __init__ method, use pass at least

Comment: Here you are. I didn't add it because the problem is not in the python logic.

Comment: Newly created ticket in PyCharm bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29043

Comment: I found one more ticker about this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11425
but it was created in 2013 :)

Answer (score -1):

If the keyword arguments are known ahead of time (and you want a docstring to explain them), then they should be explicitly listed in the function parameters. Each one can then be described with the normal `@param` & `@type` syntax. `@keywords` is used to describe the rest of the keyword arguments that are unknown at development time.

For example:

```
class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, some_kw=None, some_kw_1=None, **other_kwargs):
    """
    @param some_kw: A known-at-dev-time keyword argument
    @type some_kw: str
    @param some_kw_1: Another known-at-dev-time keyword argument
    @type some_kw_1: str
    @keyword other_kwargs: More kwargs that will be set on the instance
    """
    self.some_kw = some_kw
    self.some_kw_1 = some_kw_1
    for k, v in other_kwargs:
        setattr(self, k, v)

an_instance = SomeClass(some_kw="hello", other_kw="world")
print an_instance.some_kw
print an_instance.some_kw_1
print an_instance.other_kw
```

Output

```
> "hello"
> None
> "world"
```

Comment: The point is to not have them there but have PyCharm suggest them to you.